# pymongo.find() timing out but working with limit of same volume as collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Running into a rather bizarre issue right now that I'd love some help with. For whatever reason the below code runs when I add a meaningless limit (as the number of documents in collection), but when I remove the limit despite the result being the same volume the request times out. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd

mongodb = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s' % (username, password, host, port))

numdocs = mongodb[collection].count_documents({})
##800,000

#Runs in 11.7s
results = pd.DataFrame(list(mongodb[collection].find({}).limit(numdocs)))

#Times out, or runs 1hr+ mins
results = pd.DataFrame(list(mongodb[collection].find({})))
```

### UPDATE 10/22

Thanks to @phalanx's rec of running the explain statements, it looks like the root cause of this is pymongo's winning plan differing between the two queries:

```
mongodb[collection].find({}).explain()

"""{'queryPlanner': {'plannerVersion': 1,
'namespace': 'mongodb.collection',
'winningPlan': {'stage': 'COLLSCAN'}},
'serverInfo': {'host': 'mongodbhost',
'port': 27017,
'version': '3.6.0'},
'ok': 1.0}"""

mongodb[collection].find({}).limit(numdocs).explain()
"""
{'queryPlanner': {'plannerVersion': 1,
'namespace': 'mongodb.collection',
'winningPlan': {'stage': 'SUBSCAN',
'inputStage': {'stage': 'LIMIT_SKIP',
'inputStage': {'stage': 'COLLSCAN'}}}},
'serverInfo': {'host': 'mongodbhost',
'port': 27017,
'version': '3.6.0'},
'ok': 1.0}"""
```

I'm going to leave this question open for the time being since while I now have a better idea of what's going on, would still be great if someone could answer:

1. Why the different winning query plan?
2. Why is this different plan so much slower?

Planning on opening a ticket on the pymongo git, just want to make sure there aren't any obvious configuration steps I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running your query with a .explain("executionStats") to try and figure out what's going on?

Comment: Great rec! It looks like there are in fact two different winning execution plans (SUBSCAN on limit, COLLSCAN without limit). I'll try forcing subscan execution, but any thoughts as to why this might be slower (fine if not, just curious).

Comment: @Alex75 yep, I'm using the exact same filter between count_documents and find

Comment: (I wanted to comment the post, not this reply, so I deleted it. Here it is again my question)  Are you sure that _numdocs_ is equal to the *total* number of documents and not instead the number of _filtered_ ones (by your createdAt field filter) ?

Comment: Hey @Alex75 confirming that the number of docs is the same as filtered (same behavior when I don't have a filter as indicated in the updated code above).